# Is it possible to extend from a template parameter?

Tags: java

I would like to decorate a set of classes that derive from a common class (TextView). The classes exist in a library, so I cannot simply modify the base or insert into their inheritance hierarchy.

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends A {
}

class D extends B {
    void decoration(){}
}
```

In the example above, class D is the decorating class. The decorating functionality is common to each of my decorating classes.

My question is, is it possible to template the base class in Java? Something like:

```
class D<T> extends <T ? extends A> {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your question is about adding a method dynamically to existing classes? Something similar to categories in Objective-C. This is not simple to be done in Java since once a class is loaded through the **ClassLoader** you can't add anything dynamically to it.

The easiest thing that comes into my mind is to provide a custom mapping that will be by any chance external to the existing classes. Something like:

```
interface Method<T extends A> {
  public void invoke(T ref);
}

class MethodForA implements Method<A> {
  public void invoke(A ref) { .. }
}

class MethodMapper {
  Map<Class<?>, Method<? extends A>> mapping;

  MethodMapper() {
    mapping = new HashMap<Class<?>, Method<? extends A>>();
    mapping.put(A.class, new MethodForA());
  }

  void invoke(A object) {
    Method<? extends A> method = mapping.get(object.getClass());
    if (method != null) {
      method.invoke(object);
    }
  }
```

I just wrote this boilerplate code right now so everything won't be surely correct but the way it would work is this one. I guess you will need to do some runtime type checks to avoid blindly casting things.

If instead you were wondering if this is legal:

```
class A {    
}

class B<T> extends A {   
}

class C<T, U> extends B<T> {
}
```

Yes, it is. You can make a child class generic by introducing a type parameter.